# Display an element when input value is empty and hide it when input value is not empty

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an input with a paragraph position absolute to the input element.

I just want to hide the element when the input value is not empty and display it when the input value is empty.

This is the code I wrote but it's not working. What should I do please. Thanks.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("searchBtn").value;

document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener("focus", myFunction3);

function myFunction3() {
  if (x == "") {
    document.querySelector(".mypara").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".mypara").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="searchBtn">
<div class="mypara">mypara</div>
```

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById("searchBtn").value;` does not keep updating. It is the value at that moment in time.

Comment: I see. So how should I handle the issue?

Comment: So add a input event listener to the element and read the value in the function. Unclear why you are using focus.

Comment: here is working code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqb3ryu9/ - use `input` instead of `focus` and move x inside the function. x is always empty when the DOM loads if its outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need input event, not focus.

And get value by `e.target.value`.

```js
document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener("input", myFunction3);

function myFunction3(e) {
  let x = e.target.value
  document.querySelector(".mypara").style.visibility = x === "" ? "visible" : "hidden";
}
```

```html
<input id="searchBtn">
<div class="mypara">mypara</div>
```

Comment: This is the modification I made to my code and it's working

Comment: Okay. Well noted.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `focus` with `keyup` so it will always detect when you type. Also put `x` inside `myFunction3` to get an updated value.

```js
document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  var x = e.target.value;
  document.querySelector(".mypara").style.visibility = x == "" ? "visible" : "hidden";
});
```

```html
<input id="searchBtn">
<div class="mypara">mypara</div>
```

Comment: key up is wrong....

Answer (score -1):

Declare `x` inside of the event listener to update the variable each time:

```js
document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener("focus", myFunction3);

function myFunction3() {
  var x = document.getElementById("searchBtn").value;
  if (x == "") {
    document.querySelector(".mypara").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".mypara").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="searchBtn">
<div class="mypara">mypara</div>
```

Comment: This does not work !! as expected by OP

Comment: @AlwaysHelping How does it not work? It hides the div when the input contains content and you have refocused on the element, and then shows it again when you delete the input's content and refocus again. Was that not OP's goal?

Comment: focus is not the right event...

Comment: It's true, focus is not the right event; input event works perfectly!